# sFTP works on my new file server running Ubuntu Server - should I install an FTP server (e.g. vsftpd)?

Tags: networking, ftp, sftp, ubuntu-server

I recently installed Ubuntu Server for the first time followed by LAMP. My plan is to have a separate computer to host my websites. So, next step I wanted to allow for FTP uploading. I'd heard of FTP servers and guessed this was the step required to open a server up to FTP access (much in the same way as installing SSH server to allow SSH access). Before I installed anything though I just tried to access the server using FileZilla over sFTP .. to my surprise it worked. So I did't need to install anything?? Does that mean I have an FTP server running already? When I view tutorials of allowing FTP access on Ubuntu Server people recommend vsftpd. Why install additional FTP software when I can already transfer files? Or does this let me do more with my server? Sorry to sound like a complete beginner here but, well, I am :) Would appreciate if someone could shed a little light on the matter so I can feel I've achieved some understanding of how to do properly set up a server with FTP access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Actualiy you are better off with SFTP acess.

There are scenarious where old school FTP is to be preferred, but they don't seem to apply in your case. You will be fine with SFTP access.

EDIT: 
For a more complete answer, we need to distinguish between the protocols FTP and SFTP and the server software using those protocols, e. g. openssh and proftpd.

If we are talking about the protocols, there is a single use case in favor of FTP. Namely, you require the smallest possible bandwidth use with anonymous access. The FTP protocol allows anonymous access (much like http does) and has a very small overhead, thus allowing bigger payload per packet sent (much like rsync does.) If you only need anonymous access, use http or maybe WebDAV. If you only want small overhead, use rsync. Otherwise there is no reason I'm aware of to not use SFTP.

If we are talking about servers, there are good reasons to use proftpd (or other ftpds) over openssh. While openssh offers enough features to make secure, shell-denying access for SFTP use possible, full-fledged ftpds offer more features you might want, such as quota support, bandwidth throttling or non-system-user based authentification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm actually trying to find the difference between sFTP and an FTP server. I want to understand what the need for an FTP server is, and what it offers over sFTP.

Comment: Fair enough. I have edited my answer.

Comment: So, I can connect via SFTP using system users' login only? If I install a server, one of the things I can do is create/delete FTP user accounts (different from system accounts) to access files? If so, the term "server" here is starting to make sense to me :)

Comment: Yes, but the limitation is one of the used server software not the protocol. SFTP, the protocol, doesnt't care -- openssh, the daemon, does. That's why you can run a SFTP service via your proftpd server. You should try to keep these things separated.

Answer (score 1):

sFTP provides FTP like functionality over the top of SSH. If sFTP does what you want, that would be the prefered option. Plain FTP does not use encryption and is less secure than sFTP.

Unless you specifically need an FTP server for what you are doing, I'd recommend you stick with sFTP.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol for further info.

Comment: Under what circumstances might I need a FTP server rather than simply sFTP? What does a FTP server allow for that sFTP doesn't?

Comment: I think most use cases these days would be old software that requires an ftp server. Most modern software wouldn't require an FTP server due to its insecure nature. Note that there is an FTP over SSL protocol that some software uses, but in my experience its not very common but it does solve the insecurity issues. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS